# How to better format resume.

Tags: resume, job-search, hiring-process, hiring, inside-information

I'm looking for better ways to format my resume. As a "typical millennial" I've done a bit of job hopping and I'm looking for my next opportunity.

As it is currently, I have my 1st contract job which lasted about 6 months, then i had a touring type of contract job that lasted about 7 months, then worked a full-time job for 2.5 years, then went freelance for a year, and now I've been back at a different full-time job for about 5 months now.

I want to be able to format my resume in a way that looks less "job-hoppy" but I know I am in a tough situation. I've left every previous job for better opportunity and higher pay. 
My current full-time job since returning from freelance (where I worked on the other side of the country) is not really what they advertised in my interview and I am absolutely miserable to be honest. I'm not doing the work I was first presented any longer dispite me bringing up the issue.

Long story short, I'm looking for another full-time job but I'm not sure how to make my long list of experiences look more appealing. I currently have each job listed by month I started and left. With my freelance year, I organize it only by client and no description, just a title since there were so many. I should also note that i have done over 100 freelance gigs before I started working full-time coporate over 4 years ago, but I have been under the assumption that it's best to leave them off as it is so many and I'm looking for something full-time. All of my jobs/gigs have been in the same field. Any helpful tips? Also, apologies for typos...I'm phone writing. :-)

Thank you very much.

Comment: You likely don't have much to worry about with a 2.5-year job in there (especially with it being your last full-time job). I'd probably specifically try to mention that the freelancing was freelancing - leaving that after a year should be more neutral.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking for another full-time job but I'm not sure how to make my
>   long list of experiences look more appealing.

Just use the normal reverse-chronological format.

In the bullet points for each job, make sure to emphasize the varied experience that you have and the experience that will appeal to the particular employer at which you are interviewing. That way, it will look more like 4 years of experience, and less like 2.5 years of experience and a few short random gigs.

During interviews, don't pass off your hopping as "typical millennial" behavior. That's a poor stereotype you want to avoid. Instead, explain why this time will be different; why this time you'll stay for the long haul.

And this time dig in more deeply during the interview and look for the kind of full-time job and workplace where you really will stick around.

Comment: Should I even list my current job of 5 months, while submitting for new things? The position title could open up more opportunity for me, but I'm afraid it looks like I have not been there long enough and already looking for another place to go. Thanks!

Comment: @KaS Do you feel that a 5 month gap, which you'd have to lie to explain, gives you better prospects than 5 months experience in a well-paid position?

Comment: Thank you, everyone! I really appriciate your thoughtful help!! :-)